# Issue with Celery Not Receiving Tasks - Django Ubuntu

Tags: django, redis, celery, systemd, django-celery

I'm experiencing an issue with Celery where it doesn't respond automatically upon system boot. Here's a breakdown of my setup and the problem:

**Setup:**

- Django project using Celery for asynchronous tasks.
- Celery workers configured with the @shared_task decorator.
- Using Redis as the broker with the CELERY_BROKER_URL set to 'redis://localhost'.
- Celery workers configured to run as a systemd service on Ubuntu.

**Problem:**

- When the system boots up, Celery starts automatically, but asynchronous tasks are not executed.
- Manually starting Celery with the command `home/ubuntu/.venv/bin/celery -A febiox.celery worker -l info -E works` fine, and tasks are executed as expected.
- Checking the status of Celery service with `sudo systemctl status celery.service` shows that the service is active and running.
- However, when attempting to inspect active Celery nodes with `celery -A febiox.celery inspect active`, I get the error message `Error: No nodes replied within time constraint`.
- Interestingly, **running the same command after manually starting Celery returns the expected result showing the correct node**.

Systemd Service Configuration:

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Task Worker
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=ubuntu
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/febiox
ExecStart=/home/ubuntu/.venv/bin/python3 /home/ubuntu/.venv/bin/celery -A febiox.celery worker -l info -E
Restart=always
StandardOutput=file:/var/log/celery/celery.log
StandardError=file:/var/log/celery/celery_error.log

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Additional Information:

- Redis receives data when attempting to execute tasks.
- `sudo systemctl reload celery.service` doesn't produce any errors, but it also doesn't seem to resolve the issue.
- `sudo systemctl start celery.service` starts the service without errors.
- `sudo systemctl status celery.service` shows two instances of the Celery worker process, which seems unusual.